# How to custom in storyboard my view controller's UINavigationItem that is instantiated by identifier and pushed onto navigation stack?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uinavigationitem

In storyboard I have `UINavigationController` with some controllers.

[image]
Within the last one I have a button `Button`. When I tap that button I instantiate another view controller from current storyboard:

[image]

But here I would like to custom my `UINavigationItem` with my custom `UIBarButtonItem`s. How to do this here in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Change **Top Bar** metrics for view controller:

[image]